# Numpy "inner join" with repeating key

Tags: python, numpy, inner-join, record

I was trying to lookup the values in an array using "keys" in another array. Unfortunately due to the "space" of keys is too large (but sparse), I cannot convert this to an index trick (by using array as index).

I found the "undocumented" function `np.lib.recfunctions.join_by` which more or less allows me to select by "key" instead of index, here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import recfunctions  # necessary!

>>> a = np.array([100,200,500,700,200,500,100,700,200], dtype=[('key','i')])
array([(100,), (200,), (500,), (700,), (200,), (500,), (100,), (700,),
       (200,)], dtype=[('key', '<i4')])

>>> b = np.array([(100,10),(200,20),(500,50),(700,70)], dtype=[('key','i'),('value','i')])
array([(100, 10), (200, 20), (500, 50), (700, 70)],
      dtype=[('key', '<i4'), ('value', '<i4')])

>>> np.lib.recfunctions.join_by('key', a, b, usemask=False)
array([(100,     10), (200,     20), (200, 999999), (500,     50),
       (500, 999999), (500, 999999), (700,     70), (700, 999999),
       (700, 999999)], dtype=[('key', '<i4'), ('value', '<i4')])
```

It turns out this function does not support repeating "keys". I'm wondering how can I get a result like

```
array([(100,10),(200,20),(500,50),(700,70),(200,20),(500,50),(100,10)...])
```

which exactly **follow the order of `a` and have an extra column of lookup result**. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found I can re-map all possible keys to an index. For the `a` and `b` above, assume `b` is sorted, I can use

```
indexOfAInB = np.unique(np.r_[a['key'],b['key']], return_inverse=True)[1][:len(a)]
```

to get the mapping. I can then use index trick:

```
B['value'][indexOfAInB]
```

to get the "look-up result".

Since `np.unique` internally sorts, I believe this will take like `O(nlogn)` time. Still, any suggestion about a better way is welcomed!

BTW, this method **do not support `key` in `a` that is not in `b`**